# Screen stays black when lid is open?

Tags: windows-7, display

I'm having a problem with my ASUS K53U laptop, again.

This is happening only on Windows 7, Mint 14 KDE doesn't have this problem. It's set to do nothing when the lid is closed, in case I'm listening music, downloading something, whatever... When I open the lid, screen lights up but shows nothing, it stays black. I can get it to work again by sending it to sleep (Fn + F1) or hitting power button and waiting until it start hibernating, and then resume by pressing power button again.

I have installed all drivers for laptop, from bluetooth and wifi drivers, to chipset, graphics, Power4Gear (ASUS power management software), simply everything needed.

I should also mention this doesn't happen every time, it's pretty random, but happens in more than 30% cases.

Comment: Try to update display drivers to latest.. and feed back the result.

Comment: Tried it already, I'm using AMD 13.1 drivers, same happens with 13.3 beta.

Comment: Is the laptop connected to another monitor?  If so, have you set the laptop screen as the primary?

Comment: It could be a loss connection. Have you tried closing the lid and reopening?

Comment: No it's not connected to another monitor, and yes, of course I tried to reopen it...

Comment: found any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

There should be button to turn on or turn off the screen. Hitting that when you see the black screen should help.

Comment: It's not a essential solution.

Comment: Let's wait for OP to respond.

Comment: Yeah there is, but the only thing it does, it shuts down backlight but actual screen is still on, in my case it's opposite. As I said, backlight lights up, but screen stays black.